# Can't disable vertical scroll viewer if control size less than list box size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, scrollviewer

When my control have size less than listbox verticalscrollviewer enables automatically.

```
<ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding DropPlaces}"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: which control you are talking about? Post the control's code aswell

Comment: set ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `auto`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollbarvisibility(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ofc doesnt work. i need to disable vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Then set it to `Disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disable` or `Auto`. It's more effective if you also set `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

I hope this answer will helpful for you.